# F# Akka - Wait for one group of actors to finish before starting next group

Tags: f#, akka, actor

So I have a toy example here, where I create 200 actors and then send the first 100 a `"first"` message, before sending the last 100 a `"second"` message.

```
open System
open Akka.Actor
open Akka.Configuration
open Akka.FSharp

let system = System.create "test" (Configuration.defaultConfig())

let myActor (mailbox: Actor<_>) = 
    actor {
        let rand = System.Random()
        let! message = mailbox.Receive ()
        match message with
        | "first" -> printfn "first group"
        | _ -> printfn "second group"
        Thread.SpinWait (rand.Next(100,1000))
    }
let actorArray = Array.create 200 (spawn system "myActor" myActor)

{0..199} |> Seq.iter (fun a ->
    actorArray.[a] <- spawn system (string a) myActor
)

// First group
{0..100} |> Seq.iter(fun a ->
    actorArray.[a] <! "first"
    ()
)
// Second group
{101..199} |> Seq.iter(fun a ->
    actorArray.[a] <! "second"
    ()
)
```

What I'd like is for the first 100 hundred actors to complete (i.e. to print and terminate) before sending messages to the second group, which does not happen.

I've started looking at [Akka's F# monitoring](http://getakka.net/docs/FSharp%20API) module, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it.

Comment: For starters, I think you're calling the wrong Akka method to create your system. The [Akka F# API docs](http://getakka.net/docs/FSharp%20API#monitoring) say to call the `Akka.FSharp.System.create` function if you're going to be using it from F#, and you're calling `Akka.Actor.ActorSystem.Create` instead. I don't know Akka so I may not be able to help you with the rest, but I can at least help you fix that one mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, both lines appear to have the same behaviour, but I've edited it to keep it to spec!

Comment: I get the impression from the docs that the differences are subtle and you won't see them yet -- but the F# version will allow you to, say, use F# quotations (the `<@ @>` notation) later on.

Comment: Looking at Akka's [Actor lifecycle docs](http://getakka.net/docs/Actor%20lifecycle), it looks like you'd want to create an actor that calls the [`Watch`](http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/716F6CCE.htm) method on all 100 of the first group, and when all 100 have terminated, then and only then do you send messages to the hundred actors of the second group. I haven't yet found the right syntax to call that method in F#, which is why I'm leaving a comment instead of writing a full-fledged answer, as I can't tell you exactly how to do it. But maybe this is enough to get you started.

Comment: So this is the `monitor` functionality I mentioned in the question. The problem I had with it was that I couldn't figure out `self` in `F#` syntax, and thus couldn't create the monitors inside a monitoring actor.

The other option would be to have them created outside, and send the monitored group to the monitoring actor. I've posted a simpler system, but I may try this possibility as well and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

So I've created a solution, not sure if it's the most idiomatic, but it does the job!

```
open System
open Akka.Actor
open Akka.Configuration
open Akka.FSharp

let system = System.create "MySystem" (Configuration.defaultConfig())

let myActor (mailbox: Actor<_>) = 
    actor {
        let rand = System.Random()
        let! message = mailbox.Receive()
        let sender = mailbox.Sender()
        match message with
        | "first" -> printfn "first group"    
        | _ -> printfn "second group"
        Thread.SpinWait (rand.Next(100,1000))
        sender <! "Done"
    }

let myMonitor (mailbox: Actor<_>) =
    let mutable i = 99
    let actorArray = Array.create 200 (spawn system "myActor" myActor)
    {0..199} |> Seq.iter (fun a ->
        actorArray.[a] <- spawn system (string a) myActor
        ()
    )
    // First group
    {0..100} |> Seq.iter(fun a ->
        actorArray.[a] <! "first"
        ()
    )
    let rec loop() =
        actor {
            let! message = mailbox.Receive()
            match message with
            | _ -> 
                i <- (i - 1)
                if (i = 0) then
                    // Second group
                    {101..199} |> Seq.iter(fun a ->
                        actorArray.[a] <! "second"
                        ()
                    )
            return! loop()
        } 
    loop()

let mon = spawn system "myMon" myMonitor
```

In essence what happens is an external actor `myMonitor` sets up the environment and begins the first set of tasks **outside** its recursive loop. The actors on task now send `"Done"` when they complete, and this is processed inside the `myMonitor` recursive loop.

Once `myMonitor` has received all messages from the first block, it starts the second.